# Is it possible to remove titlebar from .NET MAUI application in windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, maui

I would like to implement a custom titlebar in .NET MAUI for Windows. To do this I need to remove the default titlebar, but SetWindowLong is not working as expected, in particular the titlebar appear to be cut in half horizontally.

The code I'm trying to use is this one below:

```
WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomFunc", (handler, view) =>
            {
                var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;

                IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
                
                SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_POPUP);

                nativeWindow.Activate();
             });
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Is it possible to avoid using SetWindowLong and use a MAUI feature instead?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the titlebar as it appears to be "cut in half"?  That would help clarify, thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised `SetWindowLong` works at all, considering "Modern" apps ostensibly don't go through `USER32`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` to your appshell.xaml
This should work if I understand your question correctly